# Simr, and interactions for multiple regression

Tags: regression, interaction, statistical-power

I have a power analysis question. I'm running a relatively simple power analysis on a linear model with an interaction term using the Simr package. Here are the data I've simulated:

```
set.seed(4) #sets a random seed so that the randomly generated data can be reliably generated in the same way again
simulated <- tibble(
  sub = rep(1:30), #creates 30 subjects
  dv = rnorm(n=30, mean = 7.07, sd = 3.9), #outcome variable
  dx_status = c(rep(0:0, 10), rep(1:1, 20)), #creates the healthy control and experimental group, coded 0 and 1, respectively
  sex = rep(0:1, 15),
  ybocs = rnorm(n=30, mean=25, sd=5)
  bdi = rnorm(n=30, mean=20, sd=5)
  )
```

I am most interested in a statistically significant interaction term between dx_status (a categorical variable) and ybocs (a continuous variable). Simr seems to specify coefficients as effects, though. So my questions are, What parameters are reasonable to focus on to do this power analysis and how can that be done in simr? (I'm finding the documentation a little more difficult to navigate for simpler models.)

I started here by specifying my model:

```
hypoth2 <- lm(dv ~ dx_status + ybocs + dx_status:ybocs, data=simulated)
```

My options to change coefficients are as follows:

```
coef(hypoth2)
```

```
Output:
(Intercept)     dx_status        ybocs       dx_status:ybocs 
16.4247335     -11.7981243      -0.2914720   0.4592288
```

But I'm not quite sure what to change or how to make sense of being interested in an interaction term to begin with. I saw both of these posts which were minimally useful:

[Simr power for interaction: how to set the effect size for interactions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448536/simr-power-for-interaction-how-to-set-the-effect-size-for-interactions)

[simr power simulation testing interaction term for 2 factors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409181/simr-power-simulation-testing-interaction-term-for-2-factors)

Thanks for any help/advice.